# How to properly using lodash throttle function in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use lodash's throttle function on onScroll event in react. Here is [implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/onscroll-with-throttle-0zqlt?file=/src/List.jsx:0-1425)  As we scroll the page i would console a message. Well, It indeed reduce total times we fire up onscroll event function. Here is the screenshot When I scroll to the bottom of the page.[image]. The part i am having trouble to understand is why I got third line output? The third line generate after 3 sec after i starting to scroll. From what i understand about throttle, It will only fire up once in a give amount of time.  But from the console message history, I saw the function always fire up twice. Did I incorrectly implement the throttle in react.js

Comment: You can use [react-bouncer](https://github.com/yairEO/react-bouncer)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace this:

```
  const throttledOnScroll = useCallback(_.throttle(onScroll, 3000), []);
```

With this:

```
  const throttledOnScroll = useCallback(_.throttle(onScroll, 3000, { trailing: false }), []);
```

Adding `{ trailing: false }` will solve your issue. You can read a bit more about this [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle).